# Javascript D3 Tree Visualization Wrapped in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, visualization, data-visualization

Getting the following error message: **Error: Problem parsing d="M,CNaN, NaN, ,"**

I'm building a D3 tree based on the Flare example (located http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html).

My primary goal is to change how data is provided to the Tree rendering code.  In the original example, data is provided via a JSON file.  In my example (located at: [http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/ed80661daf8e5fa89b85](http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/ed80661daf8e5fa89b85/)), I'm trying to provide the data in a manner that conforms more with an RDF/OWL look and feel (i.e. directly supplying a set of Nodes and a separate set of Links/Relationships).

I've changed the input data, located toward the top of the index.html, file to look as follows:

```
  var nodeSet = [
    {name: "N0", type: "Type 1", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com"},
    {name: "N1", type: "Type 2", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/glossary.html"},
    {name: "N2", type: "Type 2", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/resources.html"},
    {name: "N3", type: "Type 3", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/taxonomy.html"},
    {name: "N4", type: "Type 4", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/disciplines.html"},
    {name: "N5", type: "Type 1", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com"},
    {name: "N6", type: "Type 2", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/glossary.html"},
    {name: "N7", type: "Type 1", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com"},
    {name: "N8", type: "Type 2", hlink: "http://www.if4it.com/disciplines.html"}
  ];

  var linkSet = [
    {source: "N0", target: "N1"},
    {source: "N1", target: "N2"},
    {source: "N2", target: "N3"},
    {source: "N0", target: "N4"},
    {source: "N4", target: "N5"},
    {source: "N0", target: "N6"},
    {source: "N6", target: "N7"},
    {source: "N6", target: "N8"}
  ];
```

At about line 113, I parse the links to identify and assign Children to each Node in the nodeSet using the following code:

```
    linkSet.forEach(function(link) {
      var parent = link.source = nodeByName(link.source),
      child = link.target = nodeByName(link.target);
      if (parent.children) parent.children.push(child);
      else parent.children = [child];
    });

    function nodeByName(name) {
      return nodeSet[name] || (nodeSet[name] = {name: name});
    }
```

While everything appears to functionally work, my Javascript console is still seeing a set of "8" errors every time I refresh or select nodes.  The error manifests itself somewhere at about line 210, which is the following code block:

```
      // Update the linksÃ¢â‚¬Â¦
      var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
          .style("fill", "none")
          .style("stroke", "#000")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
          .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .attr("d", diagonal);
```

Any thoughts on what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Your `source` objects don't have any `x0`, `y0` property which you are using in the function bound to the `d` attribute in your last snippet.

Comment: Hi MarcoC1, Thank you!  I'd been staring at it all weekend.  Mind if I ask you how you used the debugger to find it? (Where did you set the breakpoint and follow through?)  Because I can't seem to easily follow the code down into the D3 link.enter().insert() block.  Thanks.

Comment: To debug it I would recommend Google Chrome DevTools: once open the tools, open the page and in the console you will see the stacktrace, expand it and click on the first line with "(index: N)".
Set a breakpoint on that line and reload the page. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in how the "var nodes = tree.nodes(root);" method works.  When it traverses the set of links to create a node tree, it is not using the original nodeSet structure, which contains traits/details about each node.  The answer is that the details in the original nodeSet have to be merged back into node tree generated by the tree.nodes() method.  Unfortunately, this can only be done by "another" iteration of the nodes.  For example:

```
      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      //nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
      nodes.forEach(function(d, i){
        d.y = d.depth * 180;
        d.name = nodeSet[i].name
        d.type = nodeSet[i].type
        d.hlink = nodeSet[i].hlink
      });
```

It would be nice if the tree.nodes() method had an API that allows the passing in of the original nodeSet so that the merge can happen more naturally, behind the scenes, and as the tree was being built (without having to add the overhead of an extra iteration, after the fact).